# Auto Upload a file

Tags: javascript, html, file, upload

I have a bitmap file at a location C:/Demo/HM.bmp
I want to upload this file using a single button or without using input type="file".
In other words, as soon as I click on a button, I want the file to uploaded using the file location as given above instead of manually selecting the file from a window(which happens in case of input type="file"). 
Please Help.

Suggest a solution in Javascript.

Comment: Before asking questions at SO, please do some research. WHEN you ask, show the research and example coding.

Comment: Anyway it cannot be done in a browser without signing the script/applet, but it can be done using WSH and file system in for example an HTA

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done in JavaScript (thankfully).

It would represent a serious security hole in web browsers if it was possible for the website to inspect and automatically upload files from the user's local file system...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this from a web page.

Here is a [rewritten WSH](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/dthomson/archive/2007/09/16/scripting-list-solutions-vbscript-to-upload-file-to-website.aspx) which may put you in the right direction. It has *NOT* been tested

Your server may have to allow PUT for this to work and the page has to be saved with extension .HTA and opened from harddisk, so it will NOT work from a web page

```
<script>
function upload() {
  var srcFolder = "C:\\Demo\\"; // note the escaped backslashes
  var strUserID = "MyID";
  var strPassword = "APasswordGoesHere";
  var strURL = "https://www.theuploadwebsite.com/puthere/";

  var HTTP = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  var fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var folder = fso.getfolder(srcFolder);
  for (file in folder.Files) { // or remove the loop if only one file
    if (fso.GetExtensionName(File)=="BMP"){
      var objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
      objStream.Type = 1;
      objStream.Open(); 
      objStream.LoadFromFile(srcFolder & fso.GetFileName(File));
      HTTP.open("PUT", strURL & fso.GetFileName(File), False, strUserID, strPassword) 
      WScript.Echo("Now uploading file " & fso.GetFileName(File));
      HTTP.send(objStream.Read);
      WScript.Echo("Uploading complete for file " & fso.GetFileName(File));
      // fso.DeleteFile(File)
    }
  }
  WScript.Echo("All files uploaded.");
  HTTP = null;
}
</script>
<button onclick="upload()">Upload</button>
```

Comment: The question is tagged `html` not `wsh`.

Comment: the question is tagged JavaScript and HTAs can have HTML. If any other answer is no, perhaps the OP did not consider HTA